# Create MimeMessage object using String content

Tags: java

How to create a MimeMessage  object using String in java

```
MimeMultipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart();
```

and need to set content from a String Object

Comment: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/243.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do this:

```
MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

messagePart.setText("You message's string content goes here.", "utf-8");
multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
```

You have to create a `MimeBodyPart` object, then set all needed properties to it and add it to  `MimeMultipart`.